# How to save non-overlapping range in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, overlap, nosql

Suppose I want to store some entities in DynamoDB, and each entity is defined by 3 crucial attributes:

- `group_id` [`string`] : the id of the group the entity belongs to.
- `from` [`int`] : the start of the range (inclusive).
- `to` [`int`] : the end of the range (inclusive).

And the constraint is:

- Within a group, the overlapping ranges are **not** allowed.
- Across groups however, overlapping is allowed.

Here are few examples of the entries:

- (`"abc"`,`10`,`21`)
- (`"xyz"`,`13`,`27`)
- (`"xyz"`,`45`,`61`)
- (`"abc"`,`39`,`57`)
- (`"abc"`,`81`,`93`)

As you can see, there are no overlapping ranges within a group in the above list. Now if we want to add an entry to the above list, then here are few examples as to what is allowed, and what is not:

- (`"abc"`,`19`,`27`) is **not** allowed, as its overlapping with the first item.
- (`"abc"`,`23`,`27`) is allowed.
- (`"xyz"`,`39`,`47`) is **not** allowed, as its overlapping with the third item.
- (`"xyz"`,`39`,`55`) is allowed.

Given this scenario, my question is, how to design the schema and how should it be used so that it can prevent users from inserting overlapping ranges for a given group?

If the solution requires some (meta) attributes to be added to the schema, I'm fine with it; I'm fine with anything as long as it solves the problem. Other related questions to ponder over: should we add each entity as a separate row? Or all entities belonging to a single group, should go to one row (with a list/map attribute)?

The possible queries on the table would be like:

- Given a `group_id` and a super-range {`from` and `to`}, return all entries having the same `group_id`, and whose `from` and `to` fall within the limit defined by the super-range (inclusive).

Specifically what are the options to decide on partition key , range key , secondary index (local /secondary) based on the queries listed above ?

Answer (score 0):

step 1 - Create a partition key (group id), range key on (from ,to)

step 2 - Restriction on from, to  fields need to be done at application level. 'check constraints' to enable this functionality is not available at database level in dynamodb

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use group id as primary key, use "from" as range key and "to" as a secondary range key (Local Secondary Index). 
Then every time you want check a new item with range between x and y, you need to do following checks:

1. Check that there is no "from" value between x and y
2. Check that there is no "to" value between x and y
3. Check that the item with largest value of "from" such that "from" is smaller than x also has "to" smaller than x
4. Check that the item with smallest value of "to" such that "to" is larger than y also has "from" larger than y

Given that all these checks are using range key queries it should be fairly fast.

Note that if your range options are limited (say range can only be between 1 and 365) then much simpler solutions are possible